# diff authentication/ authorization mechanism

Tags: security, authentication, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, javascript-security

I have a  web application build with HTML and JavaScript. Inside my application, I have to integrate with multiple other websites. To do so I have to device common secure  authentication/ authorization mechanism. I have limited control over other application and there authentication/ authorization mechanism.

- I initially considering saving password in a cookie and send the username and password in URL,  for all the application. This method is not at all safe.
- The other options I have thought about using Digest access authentication or public key authentication.
- Then I come across claims-based authentication mechanism.

Which mechanism I should chose for my web application?

Also, what do I have to do to maintain secure authenticated session?

Comment: You have to be more specific in term of your requirements. As for now, nothing else can be said than "claims-based security would certainly work for you".

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is about letting others to use your service or don't but Authorization is about privileges somebody could have for using your services like admin role or regular users.

Comment: Sounds like a comment rather than an answer.